# Remove object from object array which is present in another array

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
let existing_array  = [
    {name: "a",  age: 15},
    {name: "b",  age: 16},
    {name: "c",  age: 17},
    {name: "d",  age: 18}
    {name: "e",  age: 19}];
```

now I have a new array

```
let new_array =  = [
    {name: "f",  age: 15},
    {name: "b",  age: 16},
    {name: "g",  age: 17},
    {name: "h",  age: 18}
    {name: "i",  age: 19}];
```

now both existing_array and new_arrray has the name value 'b' and I want it to be removeed from the new array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `filter()` in combination with `find`:

```
new_array = new_array.filter(x => !existing_array.find(y => x.age === y.age && x.name === y.age))
```

You may want to use a better equality check.